# Bug on horizontal resize fullpagejs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, fullpage.js

On horizontal resize my webpage becomes bugged, in particular at the breakpoint of 993px. 993px is defined in fullpagejs as the responsiveWidth:

```
responsiveWidth: '993'
```

Resizing on the first page of the website won't cause the bug, however resizing past the breakpoint(993px) on any other page causes the top pages to dissappear from the browser window.

Reloading the page will fix the bug, so I could reload the page every time the window is resized past the breakpoint(993px). However, I'm wondering if there's a better solution.

I am not sure if it's allowed but here is the link to my webpage so you can see for yourself:

http://forgetthe.fish/

In addition to fullpagejs I'm using bootstrap for the lay-out.

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue. Steps? Browser?